# How to integrate Trading View Chart with React js

Tags: reactjs, charts, trading, tradingview-api

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";    
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";     
import TradingViewWidget, { Themes } from "react-tradingview-widget";    


const TradingChart = () => {
  const { socketData, joined } = useSelector((state) => state.socketConnection);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (joined && socketData && socketData.ExchangeInstrumentID === 500285) {
      const { Touchline } = socketData;
      const {
        LastTradedTime,
        Open,
        High,
        Low,
        LastTradedPrice,
        TotalTradedQuantity,
      } = Touchline;

      const newData = {
        time: LastTradedTime,
        open: Open,
        high: High,
        low: Low,
        close: LastTradedPrice,
        volume: TotalTradedQuantity,
      };
      setData(newData);
    }
  }, [joined, socketData]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "75vh" }}>
      <TradingViewWidget
        symbol="BSE:SPICEJET"
        interval="D"
        timezone="Etc/UTC"
        theme={Themes.LIGHT}
        autosize
        data={data} // Pass the data as a prop to the TradingViewWidget
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TradingChart;
```

## This is My code where I try to connect with the trading view chart but when data come inside the data the chart is reloading again and again.

I want that my chart candle draw on the chart with the live data. please look my cocerned.